# JQuery event listener error when using it with Rails 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have only added the JQuery using CDN, I placed the code in the head, in _head.html.erb which is this one :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then I used this code, and placed it somewhere in the show.html.erb

```
<script>
var carouselWidth = $('.carousel-inner')[0].scrollWidth;
var cardWidth = $('.carousel-item').width();

var scrollPosition = 0;

$('.carousel-control-next').on('click', function(){
    console.log('next');
    scrollPosition = scrollPosition + cardWidth;
    $('.carousel-inner').animate({scrollLeft: scrollPosition}, 600);
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure where else to place the jquery code, but when I open the console in the browser, I get this error:

```
menu-f19d6842a068966109ba6a8b3de0283869f632ec673afe222888bbeba8442401.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at addToggleListener (menu-f19d6842a068966109ba6a8b3de0283869f632ec673afe222888bbeba8442401.js:7:26)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (menu-f19d6842a068966109ba6a8b3de0283869f632ec673afe222888bbeba8442401.js:15:9)
    at S (turbo.es2017-esm.js:344:34)
    at Object.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbo.es2017-esm.js:3158:16)
    at Object.pageBecameInteractive (turbo.es2017-esm.js:3080:14)
    at he.pageIsInteractive (turbo.es2017-esm.js:2486:27)
    at he.pageIsComplete (turbo.es2017-esm.js:2490:14)
    at HTMLDocument.interpretReadyState (turbo.es2017-esm.js:2458:22)
addToggleListener @ menu-f19d6842a068966109ba6a8b3de0283869f632ec673afe222888bbeba8442401.js:7
(anonymous) @ menu-f19d6842a068966109ba6a8b3de0283869f632ec673afe222888bbeba8442401.js:15
S @ turbo.es2017-esm.js:344
notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad @ turbo.es2017-esm.js:3158
pageBecameInteractive @ turbo.es2017-esm.js:3080
pageIsInteractive @ turbo.es2017-esm.js:2486
pageIsComplete @ turbo.es2017-esm.js:2490
interpretReadyState @ turbo.es2017-esm.js:2458
```

**Edit**

the menu.js file :

```
function addToggleListener(selected_id, menu_id, toggle_class) {
        let selected_element = document.querySelector(`#${selected_id}`);
        selected_element.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                let menu = document.querySelector(`#${menu_id}`)
                menu.classList.toggle(toggle_class);
        });
}

document.addEventListener('turbo:load', function(){
        addToggleListener('hamburger', 'navbar-menu', 'collapse');
        addToggleListener('account', 'dropdown-menu', 'active');
});
```

Comment: I don't think the error is coming from this code. It's coming from something called `turbo.es2017-esm.js`

Comment: your error is in `menu.js`

Comment: @Alex I added the menu.js content, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add a listener to an element `selected_element.addEventListener` and you don't have "hamburger" or "account" element on the page. Using event delegation is a much better approach with Turbo:

```js
// menu.js

function toggleMenu(event, selectedId, menuId, toggleClass) {
  const selected = event.target.closest(selectedId)
  if (selected) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const menu = document.querySelector(menuId)
    menu.classList.toggle(toggleClass);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  toggleMenu(event, "#hamburger", "#navbar-menu", "collapse");
  toggleMenu(event, "#account", "#dropdown-menu", "active");
});
```

---

You might want to consider using `data` attributes to control the behavior from your templates. This way you won't have to add more `toggleMenu` calls:

```js
// menu.js

document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  const toggler = event.target.closest("[data-toggle]")
  if (toggler) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const menu = document.querySelector(toggler.dataset.toggle)
    menu.classList.toggle(toggler.dataset.toggleClass);
  }
});
```

```html
<div data-toggle="#navbar-menu" data-toggle-class="collapse">hamburger</div>

<div id="navbar-menu" class="collapse">navbar menu</div>
```

```html
<div data-toggle="#dropdown-menu" data-toggle-class="active">hamburger</div>

<div id="dropdown-menu" class="active">account menu</div>
```

---

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#installing-javascript-behavior*
*https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/*